3D object doesn't leave the frame, how to fix it?
I'm a VFX newbie, so thank you for your patience. I added a 3D bench to a video and motion-tracked it in Blender. It stays nicely in place until the camera moves away and the bench should disappear, but it just gets stuck in the corner of the frame and drags along. This bench will follow me forever.
Do you have any suggestions how to fix this? I am sure it's something obvious.
Thanks!



I'm guessing one of the anchor points gets caught in the corner, so the bench continues to follow it.

Hi Gina, welcome to BSE. Just two photos won't help us much. So i recommend providing your blend file, so we can check it out.

I guess @Joachim may be correct. It is not clear how you put the bench where it is - is it just an object placed somewhere in the scene without being attached to anything or is it parented to something like an anchor point? Because it could be something where the tracking simply stopped as soon as it left the view since there is no more information to track it further. And if the bench is parented to this point, it will stay where it is as soon as the tracking for the point is "lost".

Hi Chris, Right, I should have thought about that haha. Thank you! Hopefully, this link works: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mcYLHc9YhjDQvRM564Pack0J_44tA2yF/view?usp=sharing

Yes, I don't really know how to make the object stay is my issue, I thought motion tracking did that. Should I use parenting? As in parenting to the ground object, or can I parent to a point and this dumb bench will attach to it? Thank you for your help!
